# Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cuda:3! in DPOTrainer with ec2 G5 12X Large

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

```
import os
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset, Dataset
from transformers import (
    BitsAndBytesConfig,
    AutoTokenizer,
    TrainingArguments,

)

from peft import AutoPeftModelForCausalLM
from trl import DPOTrainer
from peft import LoraConfig

hf_auth = ""
peft_model_path = 'test/'
dataset = load_dataset(
    "test_classification",
)
print("Dataset loaded:", dataset)


def format_instruction(vignette: str):
    return f"""<s>[INST]{vignette.strip()} Generate given Vignette class and explain the reason for class.[/INST] """.strip()


def generate_instruction_dataset(data_point):

    return {
        "chosen": data_point["chosen"],
        "rejected": data_point["rejected"],
        "prompt": format_instruction(data_point["prompt"])
    }


def process_dataset(data: Dataset):
    return (
        data.shuffle(seed=42)
        .map(generate_instruction_dataset)
    )


dataset = process_dataset(dataset)

print("Dataset processed:", dataset)

compute_dtype = getattr(torch, "float16")

bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    llm_int8_threshold=6.0,
    llm_int8_has_fp16_weight=False,
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=compute_dtype,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
)

print("Loading base model:")

model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    peft_model_path,  # location of saved SFT model
    device_map="auto",
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
)

print("Loading reward model:")

model_ref = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    peft_model_path,  # same model as the main one
    device_map="auto",
    quantization_config=bnb_config,

)

print("Loading tokenizer:")

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    peft_model_path, use_auth_token=hf_auth, trust_remote_code=True, device_map="auto")


output_dir = "dpo/output/"
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    remove_unused_columns=True,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
)

print("Lora config added")

peft_config = LoraConfig(
    lora_alpha=16,
    lora_dropout=0.1,
    r=64,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
)

print("DPO trainer initialized:")

dpo_trainer = DPOTrainer(
    model,
    model_ref,
    args=training_args,
    beta=0.1,
    train_dataset=dataset['train'],
    # eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    peft_config=peft_config,
    max_length=1024,
    max_prompt_length=512,
)

torch.set_grad_enabled(True)

print("DPO trainer started:")

dpo_trainer.train()
print("Training done")
```

I am use G5 12X Large instance for this training it has following GPU's
GPU 0: NVIDIA A10G
GPU 1: NVIDIA A10G
GPU 2: NVIDIA A10G
GPU 3: NVIDIA A10G

But with start of dpo_trainer.train() following error will occur:

> RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cuda:3!